# Windows Store Backgroundtask with TimeTrigger not working

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

i have solution for a UniversalApp with a Backgroundtask. The backgroundtask is registered for an intervall of 30min. (limit for Phone)

But the backgroundtask doesn´t start for days. Only when i restart my whole phone the task is starting. The task doesn´t eat much cpu time, it is quite slim. The fact that the task is starting after a restart says to me that it is registered correctly. Also i can start it with the Visual Studio debugger.

How can i be sure that the task doesn´t run into the cpu quotas?

This is how i register the task:

```
await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
var registeredTask = BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.Values.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == taskName);

if (registeredTask == null)
{
    var backgroundTaskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
    backgroundTaskBuilder.Name = taskName;
    backgroundTaskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
    backgroundTaskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(30, false));
    backgroundTaskBuilder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.InternetAvailable, false));
    backgroundTaskBuilder.Register();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think a background task can have only one trigger. Since you're setting the `SystemTrigger` after the `TimeTrigger`, it is the one that the task is registered with. And so when you restart the phone, it gains Internet connection and the task is executed.

If you need to have two triggers, all you need to do is create two tasks. They can have the same entry point and just need different names and triggers.

If you want to run the task every 30 minutes **IF** there is Internet available, you need to add a condition rather than a trigger:

```
backgroundTaskBuilder.AddCondition(new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable));
```

*Note the difference: `SetTrigger` - can set only one trigger; `AddCondition` - can add multiple conditions*